# Make div stick to bottom of its container div after scrolling

Tags: html, css

I'm trying a div (later: #blue-element) to move up while scrolling down and to let it stop moving up at a certain point, even if I continue to scroll.

I have tried to use:

align-self: flex-end; Element stayed at the top.
bottom: 0px; The element stayed at the bottom the whole time, but it couldn't be scrolled anymore.
margin-top: auto; It didn't push the element down.
margin-bottom: auto; It didn't push the child element down.

HTML

```html
<div id="brown-container">
 <div id="green-element">Some stuff</div>
 <div id="blue-element>Some stuff</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```css
#brown-container {
 top: 10%
 height: 80%
}
#green-element {
 height: 1000px
}
#blue-element {
 code: that did not work;
}
```

I have a png example below

[image]

The #green-element should scroll normally.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `position: sticky;` with the `top` set using [viewport-height](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length)

```css
#brown-container {
  top: 10%;
  height: 80%
}

#green-element {
  height: 500px;
  background: green;
}

#blue-element {
  background: blue;
  position: sticky;
  top: 75vh;
}

#other-element {
  height: 500px;
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div id="brown-container">
  <div id="green-element">Some stuff</div>
  <div id="blue-element">Some stuff</div>
  <div id="other-element">Other stuff</div>
</div>
```